# Timeout annotation of testng is ignored when running it via testng suite?

Tags: webdriver, testng

When i run the code from the below google docs link with TestNG test it is working perfectly fine 
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1GHNxnZdiHbpkbJ8YTTKd4608CirQhCcNg5OTLT7SOIc/edit

But, when i run the code from above google docs link using TestNG.xml file via TestNG Suite, the annotation timeOut is being ignored and no error message is being displayed after 1000 millisecs i.e., 1sec. TestNG.xml code is also written in google docs.

please let me know how to make timeOut annotation work via testNG.xml file or also let me know if there is any other work around for it. My testng version: 6.8.0.20121120_1820

Comment: Guys, please help me out with above question

Comment: Does the test run to completion?  Does it pass or does it fail?

Answer (score 0):

As I'm seeing it, your testNG xml isn't running anything, it just knows what class to use. After `<class>` you're missing:

```
<methods>
<include name="f"></include>
</methods>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

It does fail the testcase. It's just that it doesn't show the error message. You can set `verbose=2` as a workaround to see the error message in your suite tag.